# Mixed content warning - Shouldn't HTTPS Everywhere ruleset work? (EDIT)

Tags: bug, images, firefox, ssl, browsers

Recently I've noticed that whenever I open a question that has `imgur.com`-linked images, I get a mixed content warning (and, indeed, imgur links have `http:` prefix), which is strange since I use *HTTPS Everywhere* extension for Firefox (which should set all prefixes to `https`). That also seems to be true for some other sites (which might suggest that it's a Firefox problem).

EDIT: whatever the site configuration, I expect *HTTPS Everywhere* to replace the imgur-links with their https versions (they do work on their own). Moreover the extension has a [ruleset specifically for that site](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere/atlas/domains/imgur.com.html). Isn't it correct and shouldn't that be enough?

Comment: It's all good, though it's because they are "hard coded" as http unless specifically edited. You can still access them over https though :)

Comment: @Zizouz212: I think the extension should 'specifically edit' them. Does that mean that it edits but browser still shows (the false) alarm? And how do I verify that's indeed the case?

Comment: No, the link will point to `http://i.stack.imgur.com/code`, directly. There's been requests around meta for that though, I'm not sure where though.

Comment: @Zizouz212: I might be wrong, but seems to me I've never noticed those warning before. Strange.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: I still wonder if _HTTPS Everywhere_ should handle those. FAQ suggests [it should](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere/faq#faq-When-does-HTTPS-Everywhere-protect-me?-When-does-it-not-protect-me?) but I'm not sure.

Comment: @The_Keeper: I think it depends on the specific site configuration; the data might be buggy there. Otherwise, yes, from what I know it should be perfectly capable of rewriting request URLs before they're loaded.

Comment: Pretty sure the question about HTTPS Everywhere working properly on imgur.com should be asked somewhere other than meta; [SU] might work, or [Security.SE]. It's certainly puzzling, though.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: thank you very much for this suggestion!